# taking out what is known

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

From [randomservices.org](http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Conditional.html#prp1), a **central property** in conditional expectation is
$$
E[r(X) E[Y|X]] = E[r(X) Y]
$$
where $X$ is a random variable taking values in $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $Y$ is a random variable taking values in $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and $r:S\to\mathbb{R}$ is any function.

How can we use this to prove the following "taking out what is known" rule:
$$
E[s(X) Y | X] = s(X) E[Y|X]
$$
for some function $s:S\to\mathbb{R}$.

I see that for any particular value $x \in S$, we have $s(x) E[Y|X]$ by stepping through the integrals, but I'm not sure how to use the **central property** to show this for random variable $X$. My attempt is below.

---

Consider $E[s(X) Y | X]$ as a random variable $f(X)$.
Then by the **central property**, we have that for any $r:S\to\mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
E[f(X) \, r(X) \, E[Y|X] ] =  E[r(X) \, s(X) \, Y].
\end{align*}
Choose $r(X) = 1 | X$ so we have
\begin{align*}
E[f(X) \, 1 \, E[Y|X] \mid X] =  E[1 \, s(X) \, Y \mid X].
\end{align*}
Intuitively I want to pull $s(X)$ outside of the expectation, but I'm not sure of the appropriate way of justifying/doing that mathematically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [definition of conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra). For any $A\in\mathcal{B}(S)$,
$$
\mathsf{E}[s(X)\mathsf{E}[Y\mid X]\times 1_A(X)]=\mathsf{E}[s(X)Y\times 1_A(X)],
$$
where we take $r(X)=s(X)1_A(X)$ in the "central property".

Comment: So I see $E[s(X) 1_{A}(X) \cdot E[Y\mid X]] = E[s(X) 1_{A}(X) \cdot Y]$, but I'm missing the last step for getting $E[X] \cdot E[Y \mid X]$. I believe it's by definition, but I'm not seeing precisely where. Would you please help make it explicit for me?

Comment: @dunno Since the equality holds for all $A\in \mathcal{B}(S)$, $\mathsf{E}[s(X)Y\mid X]=s(X)\mathsf{E}[Y\mid X]$ a.s.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you